# ASP.NET MVC: Parameter Binding to a single Nested property

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a generic "Index" page which lists all the entries for a given table and there is a side-bar which allows filtering the data in the grid. My model is as follows:

```
public class GenericFormIndexModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<IGenericForm> Entries { get; set; }

        public FormSearchQueryModel Query { get; set; }
    }
```

In the razor file I have an html  like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", controllerName, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "fSearch" }))
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Query.PageIndex)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Query.PageSize)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Query.SortBy)
            ...etc
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Query.SerialNumber, null, new { @class = "inputbox right-search-field" })
        ...etc
```

and I have defined an action as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
        public virtual ActionResult Search(FormSearchQueryModel queryModel)
        {
            //Implementation ommited
        }
```

Now, the problem is that the values from the form are indeed submitted, but do not bind to my "queryModel" argument in the action. I can see them in Request.Form["Query.Something"].

I do not wish to submit the entire Model, as it is not necessary to post all the entries and whatever else back. Is it possible to get MVC to bind to a nested property or am I stuck with using Reqest.Form[""] ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the `Prefix` property as below,

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Search([Bind(Prefix="Query")]FormSearchQueryModel queryModel)
{
   //Implementation ommited
}
```

The `Bind` attribute has other properties like `Include`, `Exclude` through which you can control what are the posted values need to be binded.

Comment: You said the problem is the values are not binded to the model and it's because the generated elements names are like "Query.Something", ... As default the model binder checks for elements that have names same as the properties names and since they are prefixed with Query in your case you have to specify that in Bind. If not check the view-source and see the names of the elements and specify accordingly.

Comment: I didn't say that was the reason.. I was only mentioning that they were indeed being sent back to the server and I know this because the values are in the Request.Form object with names that have the prefix, "Query.".. I fully expect that naming and it is correct.. what I can't understand is why those values are not binding to the specified argument type. I can only see 2 ways around this: Either use Requst.Form or pass the whole parent model in as the param.. that would work, but as I said before.. not nice to have to pass all that unecessary data back